# How do I print out numbers with added a comma and space after each scanf inputted number except the last one?

Tags: c

How do I make sure it doesn't add comma and space for the last number?
Now when i type in for example 5 60 2 6. It prints out: 5, 60, 2, 6,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int user_input;
  while(scanf("%d", &user_input) != EOF)
  {
      printf("%d, ", user_input);    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(scanf("%d", &user_input) != EOF)` will only terminate the loop if `scanf` returns `EOF`, but you probably also want the loop to terminate when `scanf` returns `0` (which it will do if a matching failure occurs before end-of-file). Therefore, you should probably change this line to `while ( scanf("%d", &user_input) == 1 )`.

Comment: Do you know how I can print out all the numbers in range <-10000, 10000> stoping before the number out of range? For example: 4 13 523 -13000 123 4. It should print out 4, 13, 523. My code currently prints out the numbers after the invalid one: if (scanf("%d", &user_input) == 1) { printf("%d", user_input); while (scanf("%d", &user_input) == 1) { if (user_input >= -10000 && user_input <= 10000) { printf(", %d", user_input); } } puts(""); }

Answer (score 2):

I like to make the first number special (no comma)... and all the other numbers have a comma before.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int user_input;
    if (scanf("%d", &user_input) == 1) {
        printf("%d", user_input);    
        while (scanf("%d", &user_input) == 1)
        {
            printf(", %d", user_input);    
        }
        puts("");
    } else { /* invalid input to begin with */ }
    return 0;
}
```

*You never know what is the last number ... but you always know what is the 1st number!*

Comment: Well, if you don't know either the first or last value to print use 1 temporary variable: `int commaneeded = false;` ... after you print the first value (without a comma), print all following valid values with a preceding comma (`commaneeded = true;`).

Comment: // Now when i type in for example: 4 13 523 -13000 123 4. It prints out 4, 13,  523, 123, 4. Do i have to break it in order to let it stop printing after 523?
   if (scanf("%d", &user_input) == 1)
    {
      printf("%d", user_input);
      while (scanf("%d", &user_input) == 1)
      {
        if (user_input >= -10000 && user_input <= 10000)
        {
        printf(", %d", user_input);
        }
      }
      puts("");
    }

Comment: Yes, `break` (leave the while body) look great.

Comment: Now the problem is when I added break after printf(", %d", user_input) in the if statement. It stops at 4, 13 instead of 4, 13, 523